# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot use Authentication option with Integrated Security option

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I am trying to connect to a SQL server using PHP using Windows Active Directory Authentication. My code is below:

```
<?php

$serverName = 'vgissql';
$connectionInfo = array('Database'=>'gis', "Authentication"=>'ActiveDirectoryPassword');

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($con){
    echo "Connection established";
}else{
    echo 'Connection failed<br>';
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), True));
}

?>
```

I am getting an error:

Connection failed
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => FA001 [SQLSTATE] => FA001 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot use Authentication option with Integrated Security option. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot use Authentication option with Integrated Security option. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => FA001 [SQLSTATE] => FA001 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot use Authentication option with Integrated Security option. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot use Authentication option with Integrated Security option. ) )

I can't find a way to turn off Integrated Security. And I'm not specifying to use it anywhere as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to SQL Server with Windows authentication, don't set `Authentication` connection option. Execute your script like this:

```
<?php
$serverName = 'vgissql';
$connectionInfo = array('Database'=>'gis');

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($con){
    echo "Connection established";
}else{
    echo 'Connection failed<br>';
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), True));
}
?>
```

Based on documentation about how to [Connect Using Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-2017), `"Authentication"=>'ActiveDirectoryPassword'` config option is used to connect to SQL Server using Azure AD.

Comment: I want to use Active Directory Authentication. Is that the same thing as Integrated Security?

Comment: @sdMarth When you use windows authentication, the credentials are taken from the running web server process. You need to set your WEB server to use this kind of authentication. Then, your script will under domain user credentials. I hope this comment is not too late. I've missed your question. Thanks.